# What does the Workperformer class id in Filenet represents(F_WPclassID)

Tags: websphere, filenet-p8

I need to clarify what is the use of the Work performer class id in VWdb (process engine db) . I could find some numbers assigned to the F_WPClassid to it. I dont know what those number represents.
Is it some kind of identifier. Does anyone know the use of this ID.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [list in the documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSNW2F_5.5.0/com.ibm.p8.pe.user.doc/bpfwd039.htm) explaining all the PE system fields. For this particular field it states:

> Internal identifier of the work performer class of the queue that contains the work item.

This still does not answer your question. But if you use de process engine application "vwtool" you can get more information. Details how to start vwtool can be found [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSNW2F_5.5.0/com.ibm.p8.pe.vw.doc/bpfvl056.htm). The best way to analyse this is to dump you region configuration to a file. So the first command you give in vwtool is:

```
hardcopy
```

This will prompt you for a location where you want to store the output. The next command is:

```
configdetails
```

This will print the configuration of your isolated region to the output file. It will work the fastest if you turn paging of. Next you have to give the `hardcopy` command again to stop hard copying.

If you do a search in this file for "F_WPClassid" you will see that this field is coupled to all the event log tables in your system. Finally, if you search for "Repository class ID" you will see the different values of F_WPClassid. These values correspond to the queue that processed the work item.